# Use gostscript 9.21 to convert text to outlines, and how to keep the resolution of the picture

Tags: ghostscript

I use gostscript to convert text to outlines with the following code :`gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNoOutputFonts -f test_new.pdf`,it works.But i got a very small output file from 2.5M to 70kb.Then i find the picture became blurred in pdf.

Add `-dPDFSETTINGS=/default`,This will have the same result.

I's better to use `-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer or -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress`,but 300dpi is not enough for me(or for my boss).

Is there any way to keep the original resolution of the picture.

Or how to set a higher dpi for images in output pdf.

The test file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcr7sysevt9bifa/test_new.pdf?dl=0).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is 'yes' (but see later). Don't use `PDFSETTINGS`, that sets **lots** of things all in one go. If you want control then you need to specify each setting individually.

Rather than use this shotgun approach you need to read the documentation, decide which controls affect areas you want to change, and alter those controls only.

However, image downsampling is not your problem. If you don't use `-dPDFSETTINGS` then PDF file written by Ghostscript contains an image at exactly the same resolution as the image in the original file.

Your problem is that the image is being written with JPEG compression, and JPEG is a lossy compression, so you are losing fidelity. Note that in the original file the image is written uncompressed, which is why its so large.

It looks like the original image was a JPEG, and the free PDF editor you are using has realised that so it saved the image uncompressed (I may be giving it too much credit here, it may save all images uncompressed). Applying JPEG to an image which has already been quantised simply amplifies the artefacts.

Instead you need to specify that you want images compressed with Flate, which is a lossless compression. The documentation for the pdfwrite controls can be found [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/VectorDevices.htm#PDFWRITE), you need to change AutoFilterColorImages and ColorImageFilter.

Note that by not applying JPEG quantisation (a second time) and DCT encoding, the compression is less than your first experience. For me the output file comes in at just over 600Kb (leaving the font in place, and the text as text, would be a couple of Kb smaller). However the image is identical, as expected.

Since you are clearly using Ghostscript in a commercial environment, can I just point you at the licence and ask you to check that your usage is compatible with the AGPL, bearing in mind that this covers software as a service usage as well.

Comment: And Thank you for the AGPL reminding.And I'm studying whether ghostscript can do what we want. If it can, I would recommend the company to buy commercial copyrights, or an independent open source tool. But first I have to learn how to use it.